# WooCommerce checkout issue and 'Return To Shop' button

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, checkout

I am currently working on https://shepherdsbarber.com/

1. Every time I add a product to the cart and then press 'PROCEED TO CHECKOUT' I simply receive the transition screen. This is where it should take me to: https://shepherdsbarber.com/checkout/
2. Every time I add a product to the cart and remove the item from the cart I get a message saying 'your cart is currently empty' and below that there is a button saying 'Return To Shop' but this button takes me back to the home page not the shop page. This is where it should take me to: https://shepherdsbarber.com/shopping/

Please could you help me resolve these issues. 
They have been annoying me for weeks and I've sifted through SO MANY websites!

I am not an experienced coder so please don't ask me to add to the functions.php file.

Thank you,

Lizzie

Comment: Anything customized in woocommerce ?

Comment: There is some error in JS file ajaxify.js saying "wp.media.view.settings.post is undefined". Look into this.

Comment: Did you set the shopping page in the wc settings? And what theme and plugins are you using? They seem to cause some js errors.

Comment: I'm using Salient, I've deleted all unnecessary plugins

Comment: Salient has an ajaxify script that tries to fetch the checkout page with just ajax it seems. It's breaking. Go to WooCommerce->Stattus to see what errors you are getting. What version of the theme and plugin are you using. They may not be compatible if not updated to working together. I'd try to contact theme author and ask for help. They probably have a better idea.